# Alljoyn - Scons - Services overview?

Tags: build, scons, alljoyn

Building Alljoyn on my Raspberry Pi B, I used the SCONS_FLAGS

CPU=arm OE_BASE=/usr CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

seeing that others additionally use for example:

SERVICES="about,notification,controlpanel,config,onboarding"

I was wondering is there some overview over which services are available. (couldn't find any listing of the possible options)

So would be nice if someone how knows if there is a place to look for those options can help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the possible options run your normal scons command with the -h flag added.

Here is the main documentation page: https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/learn/base-services

Here is the main wiki page: https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/baseservices/start